# WebResource.axd blank or not found

Tags: asp.net, dll, webresource.axd, .net-assembly

I'm trying to export a control library in a .dll for other developers in the office to consume.

The solution I original created looks like this:

**Solution 1:**
 - Mri.Controls (Class Library)
 - Mri.FmTool (Web Application)

Mri.FmTool references Mri.Controls.

Inside Mri.Controls, I have some javascript WebResources. Mri.FmTool seems to read the WebResources just fine, all my javascript web resouces appear as they should when Mri.FmTool web app is running.

So, now I was trying to create a simple solution to consume Mri.FmTool

**Solution 2:**
 - Mri.ConsumerTest (Web Application)

I took the latest Mri.Controls.dll and added it as a reference to Mri.ConsumerTest application. All the controls from Mri.Controls seem to be working inside Mri.ConsumerTest. Intellisense is working, it compiles, no issues.

However, when running it, most of the WebResource.axd files are empty, just blank. One WebResource.axd file isn't blank, it simply says "This resource cannot be found."

Here are the properties of the javascript files inside the Properties window:
Build Action: "Embedded Resource"
Copy to Output Directory: "Copy always"

What step am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! I didn't have the *same* question, but I was having a similar problem.  Was not aware of that "Build Action: Embedded Resource" property though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that my WebResource CSS files were loading properly, but Javascript was not loading in WebResource in the new solution.

So, instead of using the *System.Web.UI.**ClientScriptManager*** used to register the WebResources, I switched over to using *System.Web.UI.**ScriptManager***. Now the files are coming out of *ScriptManager.axd* (instead of *WebResource.axd*). This seemed to fix the problem.

**Old Code before Fix:**

```
public class ScriptManagerExtension : System.Web.UI.ScriptManager
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(this, typeof(ScriptManagerExtension), "Mri.Controls.Resources.Scripts.Libraries.jQuery.js");
    }
}
```

The code snippet above uses System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager

**New Code after Fix:**

```
public class ScriptManagerExtension : System.Web.UI.ScriptManager
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        RegisterClientScriptResource(this, typeof(ScriptManagerExtension), "Mri.Controls.Resources.Scripts.Libraries.jQuery.js");
    }
}
```

The code snippet above uses System.Web.UI.ScriptManager

From my understanding, ClientScriptManager was introduced in 2.0. I believe ScriptManager is the new improved 3.5 way of managing scripts that has a lot more functionality.

/shrug

Comment: Im not sure I follow, can you post a small code snippet of what you mean?

Comment: The relevant part is a *static* function: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource()` - took me a while before I figured that out.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing the [assembly:WebResource("YourNameSpace.YourFile.js", "text/javascript")] attribute. WebResource.axd needs that attribute. You can check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442) KB article for additional info on the matter.

Comment: I already had [assembly: WebResource("Mri.Controls.Resources.Scripts.Core.js", "text/javascript")] in my assembly info....

Answer (score 2):

Are the resources set to be part of the DLL?

Open the solution Mri.Controls & view the properties of your javascript resource files.
I think that is where the problem could be.

Comment: My javascript files have the following properties in Mri.Controls -   Build Action: Embedded Resource;  
Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

Comment: THanx. This was my problem. Old resurrected project - for some reason all the resource files got reset to Content in stead of Embedded Resource.